# Cant get the form to get ace selection properly

Tags: c#, .net, forms

need help with this code anyone know what i could do? I need to have the popup's textbox translate the information to my number, this is a blackjack game for class!

```
namespace DealCard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //creates a seed number that willbe used in the dealcard method so
        //it returns different card values
        int seednum = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Adds all 52 cards pictures to the image list
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._1);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._2);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._3);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._4);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._5);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._6);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._7);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._8);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._9);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._10);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._11);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._12);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._13);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._14);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._15);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._16);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._17);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._18);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._19);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._20);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._21);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._22);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._23);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._24);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._25);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._26);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._27);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._28);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._29);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._30);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._31);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._32);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._33);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._34);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._35);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._36);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._37);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._38);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._38);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._40);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._41);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._42);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._43);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._44);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._45);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._46);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._47);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._48);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._49);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._50);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._51);
            CardPicList.Add(Properties.Resources._52);

            //Adds the first 4 card values which are aces to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(11);
            CardValueList.Add(11);
            CardValueList.Add(11);
            CardValueList.Add(11);
            //Adds the next 4 card values which are Kings to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            //Adds the next 4 card values which are queens to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are Jacks to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 10s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);
            CardValueList.Add(10);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 9s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(9);
            CardValueList.Add(9);
            CardValueList.Add(9);
            CardValueList.Add(9);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 8s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(8);
            CardValueList.Add(8);
            CardValueList.Add(8);
            CardValueList.Add(8);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 7s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(7);
            CardValueList.Add(7);
            CardValueList.Add(7);
            CardValueList.Add(7);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 6s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(6);
            CardValueList.Add(6);
            CardValueList.Add(6);
            CardValueList.Add(6);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 5s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(5);
            CardValueList.Add(5);
            CardValueList.Add(5);
            CardValueList.Add(5);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 4s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(4);
            CardValueList.Add(4);
            CardValueList.Add(4);
            CardValueList.Add(4);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 3s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(3);
            CardValueList.Add(3);
            CardValueList.Add(3);
            CardValueList.Add(3);

            //Adds the next 4 card values which are 2s to the card value list
            CardValueList.Add(2);
            CardValueList.Add(2);
            CardValueList.Add(2);
            CardValueList.Add(2);

        }
        //Defines a image list to store the picture of the cards
        List<Image> CardPicList = new List<Image>();

        //Defines a corresponding list to hold the value of the cards
        List<int> CardValueList = new List<int>();
        int randomCard = 0;
        int cardValue = 0;
        int randomCard2 = 0;
        int cardValue2 = 0;
        int randomCard3 = 0;
        int randomCard4 = 0;
        int cardValue1Deal = 0;
        int cardValue2Deal = 0;
        int cardTotalDeal = 0;
        int cardTotal = 0;



        public void btnDeal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //gets 2 random numbers from the dealcard method
            randomCard = DealCard();
            randomCard2 = DealCard();
            randomCard3 = DealCard();
            randomCard4 = DealCard();

            //assigns values to the two cards from the Card value List
            cardValue = CardValueList[randomCard];
            cardValue2 = CardValueList[randomCard2];
            cardValue1Deal = CardValueList[randomCard3];
            cardValue2Deal = CardValueList[randomCard4];
            if (CardValueList[randomCard] == 11)
            {
                popup select = new popup();
                select.ShowDialog();
                
                this.Close();

            }
            //assigns pictures to the card from the Card picture List
            pictureBox1.Image = CardPicList[randomCard];
            pictureBox2.Image = CardPicList[randomCard2];
            pictureBox3.Image = CardPicList[randomCard3];
            pictureBox4.Image = CardPicList[randomCard4];
            //adds the the value of the 2 cards to get cardtotal
            
            cardTotal = cardValue + cardValue2;
            cardTotalDeal = cardValue1Deal + cardValue2Deal;    
            txtTotal.Text = cardTotal.ToString();
        }
        
        public int DealCard()
        {
           
            
            
            int mynumber;

            
            
            Random randy1 = new Random(seednum);
            mynumber = randy1.Next(52);
            seednum += 100;
            popup select = new popup();
            if (mynumber == 11)
            {

                
                select.ShowDialog();



                popup.selection = mynumber.ToString();
                this.Close();

            }


            return mynumber;
            


        }
        

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help the community to understand your question better. If you view it from the perspective of one who might answer the question, you'd be overwhelmed by the huge amount of code. Please reduce the code to the relevant minimum and explain the problem in greater detail.

Comment: Don't do `int seednum = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks;`. Just use the standard parameterless constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what your DealCard function is doing. Is this where you "need to have the popup's textbox translate the information to my number" ? Can you describe this requirement in a different way? // Also, the variable name of your popup instance is 'select'. But you're setting the selection property on the popup base class (form).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.